# Can I do url rewriting for Salesforce public rest services?

Tags: rest, salesforce

I have the following restful service in Salesforce:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/testRest')
global class testRest {

    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost(){
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

I have this class accessible to a site, so that anyone (unauthenticated) can hit this service at https://mydomain.force.com/sitename/services/apexrest/testRest

I want to make this service accessible to the user in a shorter url, I'd like them to be able to hit the service at https://mydomain.force.com/sitename/rest/testRest

Is there a way to do this? I tried using Site.UrlRewriter with the following code:

```
    if(url.toLowerCase().startsWith('/rest/testrest')){
        return new PageReference('/services/apexrest/testRest');
```

But this redirects me to a FileNotFound page. Am I missing something here?

Comment: did you try fullURL e.g. :`PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://mydomain.force.com/sitename/services/apexrest/testRest');` ?

Comment: Just tried. Didn't work either, I get the same result.

Comment: I didn't. I finally stopped looking and told my clients that urls for services would have to be ugly.